# How to turn off ReSharper's "Find All Usages"

Tags: resharper

I am giving ReSharper for C# a whirl. I have found that I prefer Visual Studio's simpler "Find All References" over ReSharper's more detailed "Find All Usages". "Find All References" finds everything I need 95+% of the time. Does anyone know of a way to turn off "Find All Usages" and revert back the VS's implementation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to turn it off without turning the whole thing off.

Sorry, it takes a bit of getting used to.

Comment: Interesting - even mapping a key or menu item to the old command doesn't restore the behavior. Personally I like the ReSharper dialog, so it doesn't bother me.

Answer (score 12):

To restore the original VS 'Find All References' command:

1. Go to ReSharper Options > Environment > Keyboard & Menus
2. Clear 'Hide overridden Visual Studio menu items'

The 'Find All References' command will be available in the context menu of a type

To restore the original 'Shift+F12' shortcut:

1. Go to Visual Studio Options > Environment > Keyboard
2. Enter 'Edit.FindAllReferences' in the search box
3. Set the cursor in the 'Press shortcut keys' field , press Shift+F12 and click 'Assign'
4. Select 'Text Editor' in the 'Use new shortcut in' selector, then set the cursor in the 'Press shortcut keys' field, press Shift+F12 and click 'Assign'

Comment: I also had to remove the command for Resharper.Resharper_FindUsages for this to work

Comment: Thanks so much! I hate the ReSharper Find Usages window - VS is much better. Why ReSharper guys thought that it would be a good idea to provide grouping but not provide columns is beyond me. I want a flat list of usages with a column for file and project. Having to go through each group and expand it is beyond painful and wasteful.

Answer (score 2):

"Yet, selecting "None" on the Group By combobox of the Find Usages window gives a listing similar to VS's Find All References."

Unfortunately that is still a regression as the filename is not listed on the line items. Ironically the line/column coords *are* still displayed which seems a bit pointless without the context of the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ReSharper 8, and when I have many usages, I would prefer having VS's Find All References listing because it's more compact. Yet, selecting "None" on the Group By combobox of the Find Usages window gives a listing similar to VS's Find All References.