# How to find methods in C#, which usage was not found?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resharper

Ok, what am I doing wrong here?

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245963/find-unused-code) answer or [this](https://chrisseroka.wordpress.com/2013/10/28/find-unused-private-and-public-methods-with-resharper/) (illustrated even) and it doesn't work exactly how I want. I mean, the bottom line I click on sample method -> "Find usage" and got "... were not found". Then I go to my second link, check everything exactly as it is (I'm using Resharper btw) on the pictures and got some unused stuff, but many many unused methods are not shown.

Could somebody explain me why? What do I wrong?

Will it found also unused static methods in static classes?

Comment: Right-click on one of your methods that you think is unused but resharper doesn't, select Find All References from the menu.  Do you still believe the method is unused?

Comment: Find All References can be broken, so also do a find all on the function name (on the solution) it will tell you if anybody calls it pretty quick.

Comment: I advice you to not remove any code, you can find valuable code snippets in the future and also the whole method/class can be reused. I never seen Find All Referecnes to be broken, if this somehow happen just clean  and Rebuild solution and try again !

Comment: I think there is no "Find All References" after I installed resharper.. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587555/how-to-turn-off-resharpers-find-all-usages

Isn't it the same ?